# How do you tackle choosing recipients or users like Google+ and Gmail?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, usergroups

In my app, I'm allowing users to create groups and then add their friends to them in order to share data. When creating the group, I would like to be able to do something very similar to the picture below from Google+, using an Android `EditText`:

[image]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/02351cbe2971205f232dab166a9b83be.png))</sub>

I realise that the Google+ and Gmail applications of this both work by separating each user or email recipient when the person presses space during typing. This then separates them into separate entities however still displayed in the same `EditText`. What would be the best way to implement this in Android? I appreciate any assistance as currently I'm completely in the dark on this topic.

Comment: I'd simple make my own customized view.

Comment: How exactly would you manage that, any examples? Thanks.

Comment: I presume you mean like this: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html

Comment: 1. make 9patches to illustrate groups, 2, extend a viewcontainer of your choice, in it, make always a invisible edittext get focus, now after pressing space, add a image to your container, to the left side of your edittext.

Answer (score 0):

1. make 9patches to illustrate groups,
2. extend a viewcontainer of your choice, in it.
3. make always an (invisible borders) edittext get focus.
4. after pressing space, add a image to your container, to the left side of your edittext, with the text previous inputted in the edittext. make sure to text string for not being null+"" (empty)

That's about how I'd do it.